# C++ char* relative file path? (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, bass

I am trying to play a .mod audio file in an executable. I am using the 3rd party BASSMOD .dll. I can get the audio file to play when I provide the full path to the file, but I cannot get it to play when providing a relative path. Here are some snippets.

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "bassmod.h"

// define file location
const char* file = "C:/Users/Downloads/test4/console/music.mod";

void startMusic() {
  BASSMOD_Init(-1, 44100, 0);
  BASSMOD_MusicLoad(FALSE,(void*)file,0,0,BASS_MUSIC_RAMPS);
  BASSMOD_MusicPlayEx(0,-1,TRUE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  startMusic();
  return a.exec();
}
```

bassmod.h (relevant snippet)

```
BOOL BASSDEF(BASSMOD_MusicLoad)(BOOL mem, void* file, DWORD offset, DWORD length, DWORD flags);
```

The function I'm concerned about is `BASSMOD_MusicLoad`. As this project stands, the .mod file will play no problem. However, when I try to change the absolute path of the .mod file to a relative path ("music.mod"), the file fails to play. Why is that? I have the .mod file in the same directory as the executable as well as in the directory containing the .pro file -- that didn't seem to be the issue.

Also, maybe I'm missing something related to how files are opened in C++. It looks like the `MusicLoad` function *requires* that the second parameter be of type `void*`. I'm sure there are many different things I could be doing better here. Ideally, I'd like to be able to have `file` store the relative path to the .mod file and have it play that way so I don't have to hard code an absolute path. In a perfect world, I would like to supply `file` with a path to the .mod file in my resources.qrc, but then I would have to use `QFile`, I believe, which won't work because I need the type to be void*.

Any help for a beginner would be much appreciated.

---

**EDIT 01:** Thank you all for your help! I got it to work (using relative file path, at least). There are two ways to do this. Here's what I did and how I tested it:

The first case makes the assumption that BASSMOD (or whatever external dll you're using) does not handle relative paths.

```
const char* file = "C:/debug/music.mod"; // same dir as .exe
QFileInfo info("music.mod");
QString path = info.absoluteFilePath();
const string& tmp = path.toStdString();
const char* raw = tmp.data();
```

Those are the test items I set up. When I run `BASSMOD_MusicLoad(FALSE,(void*)file,0,0,BASS_MUSIC_RAMPS);`, it works as expected. That's when I hard-code the full absolute path.

When I ran `BASSMOD_MusicLoad(FALSE,(void*)raw,0,0,BASS_MUSIC_RAMPS);`, it didn't work. So I decided to print out the values for everything to see where it's messing up:

```
 cout << "Qstring path: ";
 qDebug() << path;
 cout << "string& tmp: ";
 cout << tmp << endl;
 cout << "raw: ";
 cout << raw << endl;
 cout << "full char* file: ";
 cout << file;
 startMusic();
```

...returns this:

```
Qstring path:
"C:/myApp/build-Debug/music.mod"
string& tmp:
C:/myApp/build-Debug/music.mod
raw:
C:/myApp/build-Debug/music.mod
full char* file:
C:/myApp/build-Debug/debug/music.mod
```

Note the difference? When I hard-code the full path to the file, I found that (thanks to @FrankOsterfeld and @JasonC) the current working directory was actually not where the .exe (/debug) or .pro files were located. It was actually in the same directory as the Makefile.

So I just changed it to this: `QFileInfo info("./debug/x.m");` and it worked.

Even though the problem wound up being me not knowing where the current working directory was, the solutions by @Radek, @SaZ, and @JasonC helped to find another way to solve this (plus it showed me how to get the working dirs and convert between types). This is a good reference for people who would want to use QFileInfo to determine where you actually are in the filesystem. I would have used this solution if the dll I was using did not handle relative paths well. However...

I wondered if I could apply the same solution to my original code (without using QFileInfo and converting types, etc). I assumed that BASSMOD did not handle relative paths out of the box. I was wrong. I changed the `file` variable to `const char* file = "./debug/x.m";` It worked!

Thanks for the help, everyone!

However, I would still like to get this to work using music.mod from a Qt resources file. Based on the replies, though, it doesn't look like that's possible unless the 3rd party library you're using supports the Qt resource system.

Comment: What  error code does BASSMOD_MusicLoad return?

Comment: To get that, would I just put `cout << BASSMOD_ErrorGetCode();` under the `BASSMOD_MusicLoad` line? When I do that, it just returns "2" to stdout.

EDIT: nevermind. I found the error code in the header file. "2" is `#define BASS_ERROR_FILEOPEN 2 // can't open the file`

Comment: So it clearly just can't find the file. I imagine this has something to do with how BASSMOD is reading the file. Since it's a compiled .dll, it's a bit of a blackbox, unfortunately.

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious question but just to get this out of the way, does your file still exist? Did you perhaps accidentally move / rename / delete it in your experiments? Are you sure you have "music.mod" spelled correctly (no commas instead of periods, other common typos, etc.)?

Comment: Are you sure  BASSMOD_MusicLoad considers the current working directory at all? (Its path you can check with e.g. QDir::homePath).

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, you were right! The current path for the debug build was in the directory with the Makefile, not the /debug directory as I thought. The music.mod file was not in there. I'm writing up the solution in the original post under **EDIT 01:**

Comment: @JasonC thanks for bringing that up. That actually wound up being the problem. I edited the original post to include the solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have the .mod file in the same directory as the executable.

In Qt Creator the default initial working directory is the directory that the .pro file is in, not the directory that the .exe ends up in.

Either put your file in that directory (the one that probably has all the source files and such in it as well, if you used the typical setup), or change the startup directory to the directory the .exe file is in (in the Run Settings area).

Although, based on your new comment below, I guess the problem is deeper than that... I can't really tell you why BASS doesn't like relative filenames but you can convert a relative path to an absolute one before passing it to BASS. There's a lot of ways to do that; using Qt's API you could:

```
#include <QFileInfo>

...
const char* file = "music.mod";  // Your relative path.
...

BASSMOD_MusicLoad(...,
                  (void*)QFileInfo(file).absoluteFilePath().toAscii().data(),
                  ...);
```

> In a perfect world, I would like to supply file with a path to the .mod file in my resources.qrc

You won't be able to do that because loading resources from .qrc files is a Qt thing and BASS presumably does not use Qt internally (just like e.g. you could not open a resource with `fopen`), and doesn't understand how to load resources embedded by Qt. I am not familiar with BASS but a cursory glance at [this documentation](http://wingzone.tripod.com/bassmod/BASSMOD_MusicLoad.html) shows that it also has the ability to play data from an in-memory buffer. So one approach would be to use Qt to load the resource into accessible memory and pass that buffer instead.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I wound up putting the file everywhere I could just to see if that was the issue. Still nothing. Even when I put the file in the same directory as the .pro file. That's still a good tip, though.

Comment: I may look into the memory buffer option. The only issue there is that the program hits on antivirus when I do that for some reason, which is something I definitely don't want to have happen.

Comment: @orbit See edit, I guess converting it to an absolute path might work although it doesn't really address why it's causing a problem in the first place.

Comment: `char *abspath = ...` - you are saving a pointer to a temporary value. It is memory corruption. Please, fix your answer.

Comment: @SaZ Thanks; there you go. I tried to make it more readable, the plan backfired.

Comment: This wound up being the right answer. Please see the original post's **EDIT 01** for more details. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

> In a perfect world, I would like to supply file with a path to the .mod file in my resources.qrc, but then I would have to use QFile, I believe, which won't work because I need the type to be void*.

Why do you only belive? Read Qt Doc. It will work. Don't use class `QFile` but `QFileInfo`.

```
QFileInfo info(:/resourcePrefix/name);
QString path = info.absoluteFilePath();
void* rawPtr = (void*)path.toStdString().c_str();
```

Comment: `void* rawPtr = (void*)path.toStdString().c_str();` - this pointer will be invalid at next line of code, because `path.toStdString()` is rvalue. Don't do like this.

Comment: Next mistake: you can't work with qt resource path like `:/resourcePrefix/name` outside from Qt library, because you are not sure that BASS supports Qt resource system. I beleive it doesn't.

Comment: @SaZ to a first comment: It will work until the code reaches end of the block, than the string is released from memory (i agree that toStdString() creates a copy) and becomes invalid. Until that user has to load data with BASSMOD_MusicLoad.

Comment: @SaZ to a second comment: you might be right, the BASSMOD_MusicLoad woun't find the proper location of the bytes that has to be load. And in library not supporting it might be problem. (Maybe the worst solution would be copy the file from resource to temp dir at runtime, than play it)

Comment: You wrong in first case. Temporary `std::string` will be destroyed immideately before next line of code. You may use next workaround to increase lifetime: `const std::string& tmp = path.toStdString(); raw = tmp.c_str();`. In this case lifetime will be extended to the end of scope (lifetime of tmp variable).

Comment: @Radek SaZ is correct about the result of `.c_str()` there. The `std::string` returned by `.toStdString()` essentially disappears at the following semicolon on that line, taking its `.c_str()` work buffer along with it.

Comment: @SaZ (and Radek) your solution works for relative paths, but not .qrc. See **EDIT 01** in my original post for full details on the fix. You both helped me understand this stuff a LOT more. Thank you.